# Adjust border of one side of a minipage

Tags: horizontal-alignment, margins, minipage

I have a minipage with text on the left side and an image on the right. I would like to adjust the left side so that left and right of the text has space of 2cm in width, but the minipage on the right side (where the image is included) should be as is.

My code is:

```
\begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
    \vspace{10cm}
    Text on several lines. Text on several lines.
    Text on several lines. Text on several lines.
    Text on several lines. Text on several lines.
    Text on several lines. Text on several lines.
    Text on several lines. Text on several lines.
    \vspace{10cm}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{image}
\end{minipage}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please always add code as fully compilable, but minimal example (MWE). This makes it way easier for others to integrate their solution. Also, I removed the `xetex` tag as this is not XeTeX specific.

Comment: Ok, I will do so next time. :) Just a side question: how can I ask picture related tex questions with a picture for everyone to compile with (without the need to provide an image myself)?

Comment: For this specific reason [I created the `mwe` package](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2470/new-support-package-for-mwes) which alls includes example images which are accessible in the TeX directory tree. Just use `example-image` as image name like I did. See the `mwe` package manual for further example images, there are several. Other users just need to have the `mwe` package installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood your problem correctly. 
One way to do this is to just add `\hspace{1cm}` on the left and right of the `minipage`. This works as you assemble a logical horizontal line with all `\hspace`s, `minipage`s and filler.

Depending on your real use case using a quoting environment which increases the left and right margin would also be possible. Finally you can box the `minipage` and add margins on any side using the `adjustbox` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{mwe}% for example text only
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\par\noindent
\hspace{1cm}%
\begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth-2cm}
    \vspace{1cm}
    Text on several lines. Text on several lines.
    Text on several lines. Text on several lines.
    Text on several lines. Text on several lines.
    Text on several lines. Text on several lines.
    Text on several lines. Text on several lines.
    \vspace{1cm}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{1cm}%
\begin{minipage}{.6\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can we let the image right side coincide exactly with the right margin?

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda: I fixed that now. The reason was that the second `\hspace{1cm}` had a code line break after it which is taken as a space by TeX. Adding a `%` after the `}` removes that.